# Dealing with UISearchBar in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Here is the app idea in an iPad: I have two entities modeled in core data. The Golfer entity has a one to many relationship with FittingSession, so each golfer is capable of having more than one fitting session. I am not able to post an image for the data models as I am a new user. But here are the details:

ENTITY: GOLFER and FITTING SESSION Attributes for Golfer - first_name, last_name, emailId, contactNum, picture Relationship : NSSet * fittingSessions

Attributes for Fitting Sessions - session_number, date, location, notes. Relationship: Golfer * whoPlayed

I am working on ONE view controller called ViewManager and it has 2-3 Custom UIViews inside it( Golfer table view and Fitting Session table view). I animate them in and out whenever I need them.

I am getting my Golfers list-collection in a tableview from NSFetchedResultsController. I have added a UISearch bar on the top so that I can search for any particular golfer and get the acquired result. Shall I use one more NSFetchedResultsController to get the results of the search bar? NotE: I cannot use UISearchDisplayController because if I use that and try to search for a particular golfer, it shows the results in a table view equivalent to the size of the whole view while my tableview is a subview(size 320 * 480) inside the main view(1024 * 768- landscape mode iPad).

How shall I get things working out here?